# Calling for Input displays channel and user parameters

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So my code is basically displaying a message, then telling the user to copy and paste the message and take that as an input to be recalled later.

```
await ctx.author.send('Random message not related ')
        await ctx.author.send('Random message not related.')
        await ctx.author.send(" Message to be copied and pasted")
        await ctx.author.send('Please copy and answer the quesitons above, after you have answered everything, paste the form in this chat with the answers written.')

        answerApplication = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=100.0)

        applicationTicketChannel = await guild.create_text_channel('%s' % ctx.author, overwrites=overwrites, category=category)
        await applicationTicketChannel.send('This is the form filled out by %s please wait patiently until one of our Managers can review your application' % ctx.author.mention)
        print(answerApplication)

        await applicationTicketChannel.send(answerApplication)


        await ctx.author.send('Your staff application ticket has been opened.')
        await ctx.author.send("Your ticket is <#%s>" % applicationTicketChannel.id)
```

The problem appears once you have pasted the message, the message that will be called is the following for some reason: https://prnt.sc/u0v9v8

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`answerApplication` is a [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) object so if you print or send `answerApplication`, it will return the object, not the message content.

If you want to return the message content, simply use `answerApplication.content` instead of `answerApplication`:

```py
await ctx.author.send('Random message not related ')
await ctx.author.send('Random message not related.')
await ctx.author.send(" Message to be copied and pasted")
await ctx.author.send('Please copy and answer the quesitons above, after you have answered everything, paste the form in this chat with the answers written.')

answerApplication = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=100.0)

applicationTicketChannel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'{ctx.author}', overwrites=overwrites, category=category)
await applicationTicketChannel.send(f'This is the form filled out by {ctx.author.mention} please wait patiently until one of our Managers can review your application')

print(answerApplication) #Will print the object
print(answerApplication.content) #Will print the message content

await applicationTicketChannel.send(answerApplication.content)
await ctx.author.send('Your staff application ticket has been opened.')
await ctx.author.send(f"Your ticket is <#{applicationTicketChannel.id}>")
```

PS: I used [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) instead of %s to format strings.